# Should I send an inquiry e-mail and what did they mean by this e-mail?

Tags: job-search, email, student

I am an Engineering student in co-op. This fall, my professor/employer recommended me to a company, they got back to me approximately 2.5 months later, offering me a co-op student position, but at this point it was too late since I had already accepted an offer for another placement and could not switch. Thanked them, explained the situation and asked them to keep me in mind for future, they said that they would.

Fast forward to 2.5 weeks ago, the employer sent me a message saying a position had opened and they would like to open this position to me for my next co-op placement and if I was interested to apply through a portal that was attached to the e-mail. I said I was very interested and applied the next day.

Fast forward to now, still have not heard anything back after I applied/replied to their e-mail.

So my questions are: Should I send a follow-up message? Also, do you think the most recent e-mail meant that they wanted to hire me for that position or just that it was available?

EDIT: Note that this is not me asking about following up after an interview.

Comment: Most likely *just that it was available* and wanted to make sure they had enough candidates for the job. Be patient, wait and see what happens. No need to bug someone because they work on a slower schedule than you

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Do you ever sleep?  ;-)

Comment: @MisterPositive he gets woken up by his stackexchangey-sense tingling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the email, I would gather that the intent of it was more of an invitation to apply than a guarantee of a job\co-op.

If you have completed the process online for applying, and are not getting responses to your inquiries, then m*ost likely they have moved on with another candidate*.

If you haven't tried already, a phone call may be more effective than email at this point.  If you haven't emailed them yet, then by all means do so.

Comment: I have not sent an inquiry, I was wondering if I should (I mainly don't want to "pester" them). To paraphrase the contents of the e-mail: hope the new year is going well, this might be too early for you to know but Jim opened a position at Dunder-Mifflin and would like to open this position to you for this upcoming semester. If you're available and interested, please apply through the link below.

Comment: @Curtis I updated my answer with the new information

Comment: Ok, thanks I will give that a shot, glad to have gotten a second opinion though!